# How to change the name of data frame using specific value?

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to change the name of the data frame using the specific value I get from the data's name. My [**data**](https://api.worldbank.org/v2/en/indicator/SP.POP.TOTL?downloadformat=excel) comes from the World Bank's Open Data initiative.

My code:

```
library(readxl)

API_SP_POP_TOTL_DS2_en_excel_v2_3358348 <- read_excel("API_SP.POP.TOTL_DS2_en_excel_v2_3358348.xls", sheet = "Data", skip = 3)

colnames(API_SP_POP_TOTL_DS2_en_excel_v2_3358348) <- sub(" ", "", colnames(API_SP_POP_TOTL_DS2_en_excel_v2_3358348))

indicatorName <- API_SP_POP_TOTL_DS2_en_excel_v2_3358348$IndicatorCode[1]

varName = gsub(".", "", indicatorName, fixed=TRUE)
```

And then, I want to assign the v`arName` (in this case, varName is `SPPOPTOTL`) as the name of the Data because it is `API_SP_POP_TOTL_DS2_en_excel_v2_3358348`, so long.

In short, I want to get this result.

```
  SPPOPTOTL <- API_SP_POP_TOTL_DS2_en_excel_v2_3358348
```

I do not want to type in the varName, `SPPOPTOTL`, directly.

Comment: Not recommended in general, but have a look at `assign`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option for getting the variable name, then as @user2974951 suggested, you can use `assign`. This will create `SPPOPTOTL` and add it to the global environment.

```
library(tidyverse)

varName <- API_SP_POP_TOTL_DS2_en_excel_v2_3358348 %>%
  dplyr::pull("Indicator Code") %>%
  head(1) %>%
  str_replace_all(., "[[:punct:]]", "")

assign(x = varName, value = API_SP_POP_TOTL_DS2_en_excel_v2_3358348)
```